# plot an arc line and get the conjunction with other lines (matlab)

Tags: matlab, automatic-ref-counting, line

I have a series of line which are centered in one end and opened on the other end as below picture(blue line). I would like to make an arc line over them with a certain radios and same center as blue line(red line). The goal is to have conjunction points on red and blue lines.

[image]

first problem is how to make this curve?
second is how to find the connectivity points

I used this codes to make an arc but it does not work properly because it is not line it is points of arc.

```
enter code here

P1 = [x1;y1];
P2 = [x2;y2];
P0 = [x0;y0];
n = 1000; % The number of points in the arc
v1 = P1-P0;
v2 = P2-P0;
c = det([v1,v2]); % "cross product" of v1 and v2
a = linspace(0,atan2(abs(c),dot(v1,v2)),n); % Angle range
v3 = [0,-c;c,0]*v1; % v3 lies in plane of v1 and v2 and is orthog. to v1
v = v1*cos(a)+((norm(v1)/norm(v3))*v3)*sin(a); % Arc, center at (0,0)
plot(v(1,:)+x0,v(2,:)+y0,'y.') % Plot arc, centered at P0
axis equal
```

THANKS in advance

Comment: for intersections have a look at polyxpoly (http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/map/ref/polyxpoly.html)

Comment: I don't see your question. The code you provided does what you want to. I'm not quite sure how exactly the radius is determined. To make a red line out of this you simply change the plot command to something like ``plot(v(1,:)+x0,v(2,:)+y0,'r-')``. To get the intersection you simply calculate the angle between the x-axis and the blue lines and and there are your polar coordinates with respect to the offset P0.